# Received 403 from server (Forbidden)

Tags: maven, gradle, build

Please i need someone to help me out of this, am new, I got these error while trying to build apk

> Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/faltenreich/skeletonlayout/2.0.1/skeletonlayout-2.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

along side this error:

> Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

[Error .apk]

Answer (score 0):

> New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable
> Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from
> the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle
> Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

Comment: i did that severally, the message "disable offline mode still persist"

Answer (score 0):

Please check first whether Offline mode is truly deactivated via `Help / Find Action...`: Type "offline mode" into the dialog and check whether "Toggle Gradle Offline Mode" is set to "Off". If it was set to "On", toggle it and try syncing again.

If this does not work, the problem might have something to do with the sunset of JCenter. Try a more current version of this library, e.g. `com.faltenreich:skeletonlayout:4.0.0` which is hosted on MavenCentral (`mavenCentral()`)and remove JCenter (`jcenter()`) from your repositories. Then try syncing again.

Disclaimer: Am developer of the library from the error message